# Make Ubuntu Mate Look Like Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick Meerkat)

Tags: themes, icons, mate, icon-themes

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. 
I'm wondering if it's possible to make Ubuntu Mate look like the old Ubuntu (10.10).

I want it to look exactly like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: which ubuntu mate version you are running?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Mate 15.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the `ambiance` theme installed,here are two good choices

Choice number 1: [Light Theme (Ambiance and Radiance)](http://mate-look.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/light-theme-ambiance-and-radiance-for.html)

This is the developers screen shot

[image]

Download [the .deb here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72782740/debian/light-themes-mate-12.04-all.deb) or

```
wget dl.dropbox.com/u/72782740/debian/light-themes-mate-12.04-all.deb
```

Install it

```
sudo dpkg -i light-themes-mate-12.04-all.deb
```

Resolve dependencies (should not be needed)

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Choice number 2: [Ambiance & Radiance colors](http://www.ravefinity.com/p/download-ambiance-radiance-colors.html), this will install `ambiance` with many highlight options (including the orange you wanted)

[image]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ravefinity-project/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ambiance-colors
```

Note : This PPA also has radiance colours themes `sudo apt-get install radiance-colors`

Install `mate-tweak` to change your theme

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/trusty-mate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mate-tweak
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I upvoted the answer.

I guess those themes are the closest you can get to the original Ubuntu 10.10. I'll experiment with it. 

Thanks again

Comment: Please feel free to give any feedback here on how close these themes are to 10.10 GTK theme

Comment: How do i enable this theme :O Oh it is enabled, but there is no taskbar at the bottom :9

Comment: @JamieHutber The panel is not part of the theme, you must add a new panel through the desktop, I think if you right click the top panel, you can add a new panel and drag it to the bottom.

Comment: Good thinking, I remember this is how you would do it previously. However right-clicking on the top bar does nothing, nor does doing it on the desktop offer anything :(